# Changing shapefile to stereographic projection in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have a shp file of the world's coastlines in QGIS and I was wondering how I would convert it to a Stereographic projection as shown in this map:

[image: http://www.quadibloc.com/maps/images/ster.gif]

Answer (score 1):

This question has already been asked. [Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210272/how-do-i-create-a-stereographic-projection-from-a-shp-file) a custom solution with a "Sperical Mollweide Projection" ist used.

It seems to be rather unusual to use a stereographic projection that is not centered on the poles.